# Не корректно работает imageColorAllocate()

Tags: php, изображения, color

функция imageColorAllocate() перестает работать в цикле

```
$i = imageCreate(count($hAr), 360);
$color = imageColorAllocate($i, 255, 255, 255);
/*$c = imageColorAllocate($i, 0, 0, 0);*/
$nn = 0;
foreach ($hAr as $key => $hh) {

    $c = imageColorAllocate($i, $ar[$key][3], $ar[$key][4], $ar[$key][4]);

    imageSetPixel($i, $nn, $hh,   $c);
    imageSetPixel($i, $nn, $hh+1, $c);
    imageSetPixel($i, $nn, $hh-1, $c);
    $nn++;
}
```

Если изменять $c(цвет точки) в цикле линия обрывается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но если цвет статичен все в порядке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заранее скажу: в ($ar[$key][n]) 0 < n < 255 и в массиве нет белого цвета.

Изменив цвет все равно получаю обрыв линии:

```
foreach ($hAr as $key => $hh) {
    ...
    $c = imageColorAllocate($i, 255, 0, 0);
    ...
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Кто сталкивался с таким? Подскажите как исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Причины возникновения проблемы

Прочитайте первый комментарий к этой функции на php.net:  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecolorallocate.php#94785

> Note that you can only assign 255 colors to any image palette.  If you try assigning more, imagecolorallocate() will fail.
>
> Also, imagecolorallocate() will assign a new color EVERY time the function is called, even if the color already exists in the palette

У Вас в цикле выделяется 255 цветов на изображение, а затем (вероятно) функция перестаёт их выделять и начинает возвращать `FALSE`. При этом, как поясняется по вышеуказанной ссылке, неважно одинаковые цвета вы резервируете этой функцией или разные.

## Решение для случая, когда количество цветов менее 256

Возможно, оно неидеально. Это просто идея для дальнейшей проработки:

```
function getColor($i, $r, $g, $b) {
    static $colors = [];

    $rgb = $r . $g . $b;

    if (!array_key_exists($rgb, $colors)) {

        $colors[$rgb] = imageColorAllocate($i, $r, $g, $b);
    }

    return $colors[$rgb];
}

$i = imageCreate(count($hAr), 360);
$color = imageColorAllocate($i, 255, 255, 255);
$nn = 0;
foreach ($hAr as $key => $hh) {
    $c = getColor($i, $ar[$key][3], $ar[$key][4], $ar[$key][4]);

    imageSetPixel($i, $nn, $hh,   $c);
    imageSetPixel($i, $nn, $hh+1, $c);
    imageSetPixel($i, $nn, $hh-1, $c);
    $nn++;
}
```

При этом следует понимать, что это решение не спасёт от выделения более 255 **разных** цветов на изображение. Оно спасает лишь от исчерпания лимита при повторном резервировании **одинаковых** цветов.

## Решение для случая, когда цветов более 255

В этом случае для создания изображения вместо функции `imagecreate()` следует использовать функцию `imagecreatetruecolor()`: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php

Следует помнить, что функция `imagecreatetruecolor()` расходует больше памяти (в 2-3 раза больше) и меньше подходит для работы с GIF-изображениями.

Comment: Спасибо, третий пример теперь работает.
Но повторно резервировать один и тот-же цвет в моем примере не имеет смысла т.к я могу установить его только 1 раз перед циклом.
Проблема именно в изменении цвета, для каждой точки в массиве установлено своё значение.
Нельзя ли в php увеличить количество цветов в изображении?

Comment: 1. Сколько элементов в массиве? 2. Сколько разных цветов в этом массиве?

Comment: 1600, но может быть больше.
Цветов немного меньше, т.к они иногда повторяются но тоже примерно 1600

Comment: Дополнил ответ.